# Debug a class library project within a multi-language solution

Tags: .net, visual-studio, class, debugging

I have inherited a solution where the main project within it contains a main form that acts as host for the other projects, which act as either tabs in that form, or commands in its menus.

All the projects in there I created, for which there is a form acting as a tab, I can launch in debug mode in Visual Studio, no problem, even though they are, by definition, class libraries.

But with this new project I created, by copying most of the code from an existing, working project, for which I have no issue to launch in debug mode, Visual Studio simply refuses to do it.

I checked and rechecked, all settings are strictly identical to the other projects VS accepts to debug, I see no reason why it shouldn't accept to do it for this one.
Any idea?

PS: I tried in VS 2017, 2019 and 2022, no joy. The solution includes projects in VB.Net and C#, .Net Frameworks vary from project to project, but here, it's the same as one which works.

Comment: Perhaps there is some application configuration that need an update to recognize a new tab

Comment: Not a bad idea, so I checked the main project, see where it refers to the other projects, and put the new project there, but no joy.

Comment: In the meantime, I put the main form in debug mode. It's a bit awkward, in that I have to first compile the project I actually want to test, and put the resulting dll where the main form will take it, but at least, I can debug...

Comment: In the project properties you can use the Building Events page and add a batch command to copy your dll from the output folder of the current project to the output folder of the main project. This is needed if your dll are loaded at runtime and not statically referenced in the main project.